# How to save a large recovered hard disk data from computer directly into cloud storage

Tags: ftp, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, cloud-storage

Recently, I did some data recovery from my damaged hard disk using third-party data recovery software. Since the data recovered almost 1TB, I need backup storage to store my recovered data. I do not own any physical drives to store my recovered data at the moment. So, I rented 1TB cloud storage temporarily while waiting for my physical backup drive to arrive, which will be available after 2-3 weeks later.

Luckily, I'm able to recover all the data from my damaged hard drive. Unfortunately, the recovery software that I used does not provide an option to save all the recovered data directly through my rented 1TB cloud storage. I have tried several methods by using FTP, but it uses my current drive storage to barely store the data because I need to save the recovered data somewhere on the computer first and then upload it via FTP.

How am I able to save it directly into my cloud storage as the destination folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that the data has not been recovered yet and is still on damaged drive. Your recovery software requires “local storage”. So, you need to mount cloud storage such way, that it will be recognized as a local. Here are tools which can do this for S3 compatible cloud storage:

1. Linux and MacOS – S3FS https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
2. Windows – TntDrive (30 days free trial) https://tntdrive.com/ . Tntdrive mounts S3 bucket as a network drive, so if your recovery software is unable to write on network drive, just create “directory junction” on local C:, which points to network drive.

If you are looking for backup software, which can write directly in cloud storage, here a list of couple of them- http://www.vmwareblog.org/single-cloud-enough-secure-backups-5-cool-cross-cloud-solutions-consider/